# How can I use my SQL query in the cursor query or other method?

Tags: sql-server

The following SQL query returns the result I want for just one table.

```
SELECT [NoMatchExplanation], COUNT(*) 
FROM err.CustomerBank 
GROUP BY (NoMatchExplanation)
```

I would like to do this for all the tables in the query below that are bringing the tables whose schema is 'err'.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err'
```

The output of the above SQL query:

```
err.ColleteralValuablePaper
err.CustomerPayment
err.CustomerPaymentItemMatching
err.DealerColleteralPercent
err.DealerDistributorStatus
err.DealerShellLimit
err.DealerWaitingLimit
err.DistributorPreFinanceLimit
err.ColleteralValuablePaper
.
.
.
```

Each row is a table name. I want to write a SQL query that will repeat the operation for each row in the first SQL query.

How can I do this with a cursor or other method? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every table in the err schema contains a column named 'NoMatchExplanation', the query below should work:

```
declare @table_name sysname;
declare @stmt nvarchar(max);

create table ##temp(NoMatchExplanation nvarchar(250), cnt int);

declare cur_tables cursor for
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'err';

open cur_tables;

fetch next from cur_tables into @table_name;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    set @stmt = 'INSERT INTO ##temp(NoMatchExplanation, cnt) SELECT NoMatchExplanation, COUNT(*) FROM ' + @table_name + ' GROUP BY NoMatchExplanation';
    exec(@stmt);

    fetch next from cur_tables into @table_name;

end

select * from ##temp;
drop table ##temp;

close cur_tables;
deallocate cur_tables;
```

Comment: Firstly thank you. how do I record the results in a single table ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to use a global temporary table (a local temporary table wouldn't be available outside of the dynamic query).

Comment: How does index fragmentation break down?